# Go-Sublime-build configuration

Tags: go, sublimetext2

Im having issues trying to set up go to run the current file from Sublime text 2. 
Here's what I have in my go.sublime-build file

```
{
    "cmd": [ "go", "run", "${file}" ]
}
```

When I try to run build on a go source file, I get the error

```
[Error 6] The handle is invalid
[cmd:  [u'go run', u'C:\\Users\\gprasant\\Documents\\GitHub\\programming_pearls\\src\\go\\quicksort.go']]
[dir:  C:\Users\gprasant\Documents\GitHub\programming_pearls\src\go]
```

Is there any way to get this fixed ? Or is there another plugin in Sublime text for Go development?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime) should get this working for you. After installing and restarting ST2: do ctrl-B, type "run" and hit enter.

Comment: I agree, that's a great plugin. It also runs go fmt for you when you save.

Comment: I agree that GoSublime is a good plugin, but its concept of offering a shell which, among other tasks, allows you to enter a command which builds the current package, doesn't go far enough IMHO. If I have a build feature inside an editor, I expect to be able to double-click on an error message and be taken to the file/line containing the error. The current feature is pretty pointless - you might as well use an external shell, then you don't have to remember an extra command and you have more space for displaying error messages.

Comment: GoSublime didn't solve the issue for me. What did was writing a custome go.sublime-build file as shown below.

Comment: I do type run but it builds all files in directory not current opened file.

Answer (score 8):

I got by with

```
{
    "cmd": "go run $file",
    "shell" : true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On my mac, I needed the following code in:

```
/Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/go.sublime-build
```

go.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["go run '${file}'"],
    "selector": "source.go",
    "path": "/usr/local/go/bin",
    "shell": true
}
```

- "cmd" line quoting is to correctly handle file paths with spaces.
- "shell" line is needed since commenting it out breaks it.
- "path" line is needed because the basic shell, doesn't have access to my .zshrc file include the export GOPATH statement defining the go path.

After that any .go file should build and run with command+B, leaving the stdout message in a console built into sublime text 2.

Comment: When I use these exact commands - the file will build, but I don't see any output... just `[Finished in 0.0s]`. Any hints?

Comment: This worked pretty good, thankss!, on linux the key strokes would be : control + b

Answer (score 5):

In ST3: it is changed to be:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "go run ${file}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
{
    "cmd": ["go", "run", "${file}"],
    "path": "/user/local/go/bin"
}
```

I like GoSublime, just hate to type run each time when click Command + B

Comment: what is the "path" for? Is it required even if I have my go tools' path in the environment PATH ?

Comment: @gprasant , from http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html path "will replace the current process’ PATH before calling cmd", if it's true, maybe we needn't this. but I can't get it work until I added this line.

Comment: @sunqjiang I tried what you recommended. It worked when i did Ctrl + B. One more thing I tried is removing the path my sublime-build file and then restarting ST2. Even that worked.

Comment: @gprasant glad to hear this. and recommand https://tutsplus.com/lesson/custom-builds/ at about 5:58, it says "for some reason, if it can't recognize ..., you may need full path or you could set it right here". no idea why it need path statement one time yet.

Comment: There are shortcuts available Preferences->Package Settings->GoSublime-> Key Bindings (super+. super+r)

Answer (score 0):

SublimeText 2
build-system for golang, making F4/shift-F4 **work** (next error/prev error)

1st, create a file: ~/gosublime_build.sh

```
GOPATH=~/go
export GOPATH 
echo "GOPATH:$GOPATH"

if [ "$3." = "RUN." ]
  then 
     EXENAME=${1##*/}
     EXENAME=$GOPATH/bin/$EXENAME
     echo $EXENAME
     $($EXENAME)
     echo "code: $?"
     exit
fi

echo "go build $2"
cd /usr/local/go/bin
./go build -o ~/temp.go.compiled $2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
   cd $1
   echo "Project: " $1
   /usr/local/go/bin/go install
   echo "go install exit code: $?"
 else
   echo "go build exit code: $?"
fi
```

2nd:

```
chmod 777 ~/gosublime_build.sh
```

3rd: create a new sublime2 build-system for "go" (Tools/Build System/New)

```
{
"cmd": ["~/gosublime_build.sh $file_path $file"]
,"shell": true
,"selector": "source.go"
,"file_regex": "([\\w/_-]+[.]{1}[\\w./_-]+?):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?(.*)?"
}
```

4th: select your new build-system (Tools/Build System)

5th: build with Ctrl-B, F4/Shift-F4: next/prev error

If anybody knows how to instruct the go compiler to inform FULL PATH of file and line for each error, this process can be simplified